# How do I get comments in a noweb expansion?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Given the org-mode file

```
* File Description
  :PROPERTIES:
  :comments: org
  :tangle:   file.sh
  :noweb: yes
  :END:

** A function call
This is foo
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :noweb-ref myfunction :tangle no
hello_world()
#+END_SRC

** Additional info
This is bar
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :noweb yes
  hello_person()
  <<myfunction>>
#+END_SRC
```

When I tangle the file with <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-v</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd>, my expectation would be the following result.

```
# Additional info
# This is bar

hello_person()

# A function call
# This is foo

hello_world()
```

But this isn't what happens, The comment from the `myfunction` noweb-ref is stripped from the final result and it looks like this.

```
# Additional info
# This is bar

hello_person()
hello_world()
```

Is there a native way to get this behaviour or do I advise `org-babel-expand-noweb-references`?

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no option to enable this: in `org-babel-expand-noweb-references` `<<foo>>` is (unconditionally) expanded to the **contents** of the named source code block `foo`, not the section containing this source code block.

Comment: @Constantine This is helpful, Thanks!